# What are the use cases for streaming functionality of Mustache?

Tags: javascript, mustache

From the [mustache's documentation](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#readme):

> To stream template results out of mustache.js, you can pass an optional send() callback to the to_html() call:

```
Mustache.to_html(template, view, partials, function(line) {
    print(line);
});
```

Maybe it's me failing to understand the doc. I am sure it's a useful feature, but I cannot find good use cases for it. Can anyone please enlighten me?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's so you can take completed lines one by one out of the template expansion process. It's not clear why that would be useful, I agree.

Comment: For future reference: it is useful because the browser can start rendering the partially returned document. This can give a  performance increase especially because assets on the top of the document can start loading before the entire page has returned from the server. Assets: think CSS and JS-loaders (such as Headjs). HTH

Answer (score 1):

If you are rendering the template on the server, streaming allows you to start transmitting the document as it is being rendered.  Otherwise, you have to render the entire document in memory before sending it to the browser.

**EDIT**

I see that you tagged the question with javascript, so my answer might not apply if you are referring to client side javascript.